# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray Ethers.js encrypt function error

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

```
const jsonKey = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

const encrypTkey = jsonKey.encrypt(process.env.PASSWORD);
```

Code is throwing error saying

```
**TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Promise**
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we are missing await keyword.

const jsonKey = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

const encrypTkey = **await** jsonKey.encrypt(process.env.PASSWORD);

It should work now.